# How to update data in database table using conditional expression

Tags: python, django

I want to update my data in my database table only if conditional expression work.

I have a dictionary called result_total which is continuously updated. Using for loop condition I want to update my data. For example: if  result_total[news_item][2] is equal to any of my database table entries then result_total[news_item][2] will not be updated

```
for news_item in result_total:
    if Haberler.objects.get(haber_link=result_total[news_item][2]):
        Haberler.objects.filter(sira_no=news_item).update(
            haber_id=result_total[news_item][0],
            haber_baslik=result_total[news_item][1],
            haber_link=result_total[news_item][2],
            haber_imagelink=result_total[news_item][3],
            haber_text=result_total[news_item][4]
        )
```

error messages shows following "Haberler matching query does not exist."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
if Haberler.objects.get(haber_link=result_total[news_item][2]):
```

use:

```
if Haberler.objects.filter(haber_link=result_total[news_item][2]).exists():
```

Comment: Thank you Milkyway. It worked. You really helped me.

Comment: Glad to help. So please consider accepting the answer.